# Jackson, можно ли обработать динамический массив?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Есть такой Json

```
 "color": {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "GMF",
            "images": {
                "1": {
                    "type": "main",
                    "title": "Replica A996 GMF",
                    "big": "http://shop.wheelshop.com.ua/photo/wheels/b/Replica-A996-GMF.png",
                    "average": "http://shop.wheelshop.com.ua/photo/wheels/a/Replica-A996-GMF.png",
                    "small": "http://shop.wheelshop.com.ua/photo/wheels/s/Replica-A996-GMF.png",
                    "micro": "http://shop.wheelshop.com.ua/photo/wheels/m/Replica-A996-GMF.png"
                },
                "5": {
                    "type": "live",
                    "title": "Replica A996 GMF",
                    "big": "http://shop.wheelshop.com.ua/photo/wheels_live/b/Replica-A996-GMF.png",
                    "average": "http://shop.wheelshop.com.ua/photo/wheels_live/a/Replica-A996-GMF.png",
                    "small": "http://shop.wheelshop.com.ua/photo/wheels_live/s/Replica-A996-GMF.png",
                    "micro": "http://shop.wheelshop.com.ua/photo/wheels_live/m/Replica-A996-GMF.png"
                }
```

В строке `images` есть динамические массивы `1`, `5`, тоисть в одном запросе это может только блок `1`,а в другом запросе и вовсе блок `3`. Но проблема в том, что карта Json в Jackson должна быть четко прописана,если что-то меняется, то не работает ничего. Есть ли вообще решение для такого случая?

Попробовал распарсить так

```
public class PjColorImages {
Map<String, PjColorImagesMain> properties_main;

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, PjColorImagesMain> any() {
    return properties_main;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String name, PjColorImagesMain value) {
    properties_main.put(name, value);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PjColorImages{" +
            "properties_main=" + properties_main +
            '}';
}
```

Но выдает такой exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A (through reference chain: com.example.PjMain["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.PjMainData["color"]->com.example.PjColor["images"]->com.example.PjColorImages["i1"])
```

Код класса `PjColorImagesMain`

```
public class PjColorImagesMain {
private String type,title,big,average,small,micro;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getBig() {
    return big;
}

public void setBig(String big) {
    this.big = big;
}

public String getAverage() {
    return average;
}

public void setAverage(String average) {
    this.average = average;
}

public String getSmall() {
    return small;
}

public void setSmall(String small) {
    this.small = small;
}

public String getMicro() {
    return micro;
}

public void setMicro(String micro) {
    this.micro = micro;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PjColorImagesMain{" +
            "type='" + type + '\'' +
            ", title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", big='" + big + '\'' +
            ", average='" + average + '\'' +
            ", small='" + small + '\'' +
            ", micro='" + micro + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

Comment: Сделано, обновил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

содержимое `images` можно распарсить так:

```
Map<String, ImageInfo> properties = new HashMap<>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, ImageInfo> any() {
    return properties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String name, ImageInfo value) {
    properties.put(name, value);
}
```

здесь `ImageInfo` - класс, описывающий содержимое блока 1/5/3/etc из примера

**UPDATE:**
В коде класса в вопросе забыта инициализация Map

```
Map<String, PjColorImagesMain> properties_main = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Обновил тело письма, выдает excepcion

Comment: спасибо, очень помогли